# How to get username after valid authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have question regarding to expose my API by using `Wso2 API manager`. The setting up such as creating API user role are done, i can use consumer key and consumer secret to exchange access token and use it to invoke API endpoint successfully.

I am still wondering that is it possible to get user name valid authentication and transfer it to production endpoint as path parameter or query parameter ?

For example, my production endpoint is: `_http://localhost/myapi`, and after valid authentication, Wso2 AM server will redirect request to: `_http://localhost/myapi/my-user-name` or `_http://localhost/myapi?username=my-user-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at passing a [JWT token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) to the back-end. By this you can pass the user information and some API related information to the back-end via a header.